# Postgresql: Is the following select reasonable/possible?

Tags: postgresql

A customer would like me to create a dataset as the shown below. I have no idea if this is possible or logical.

I have table **parent**:

```
id       name 
-------  -------
1        parent1
2        parent2
3        parent3
```

And table **child**:

```
id       parent   name     age
-------  -------  -------  -------
1        1        child1   2
2        1        child2   4
3        1        child3   7
4        2        child12  5
```

I would like to make a select query to return the following for **parent1**:

```
parent   child1   child2   child3
-------  -------  -------  -------
parent1  2        4        7
```

And of course return the following for **parent2**:

```
parent   child12
-------  -------
parent2  5
```

Anyone has a solution for this, or a creative comment?

Comment: A SQL query always returns the same number of columns. So a single statement can't return 4 column once and 2 column another time. The only way this could be done is by returning the children e.g. as a comma separated list or an array (in a single column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tablefunc PostgreSQL extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

```
create extension tablefunc;
```

I defined tables as:

```
create table parent (id integer, name text);
create table child (id integer, parent integer, name text, age integer);
```

To create a pivot table, you need to specify two queries, first is the data query and returns tuples of (key1, key2, value):

```
SELECT P.name, C.name, C.age from parent P, child C where P.id = C.parent and C.parent = 1
```

The second defines the column names and types:

```
select C.name from child C where C.parent = 1
```

Then use the crosstab function:

```
select * from crosstab(
    $$ SELECT P.name, C.name, C.age from parent P, child C where P.id = C.parent and C.parent = 1 $$,
    $$ select C.name from child C where C.parent = 1 $$
) AS (name text, child1 integer, child2 integer, child3 integer);
  name   | child1 | child2 | child3 
---------+--------+--------+--------
 parent1 |      2 |      4 |      7
(1 row)
```

**Note** that it's a bit tricky to generate this dynamically, since you **need** to specify column types (the AS part after the crosstab function), which means you need to make another query to know how many distinct labels (child1, child2 and child3 in this case) will there be.

Buuut, while this query is possible, it may not be the best case for your problem. I use it as a helper when doing analysis, and even then it is frequently easier to just export the (key1, key2, value) table and pivot in Excel/LibreCalc. Crosstab also has a limitation of only two keys, where Excel supports more fields and its really fast and easy dragging them around.

Answer (score 1):

If json is good enough:

```
with parent (id, name) as ( values
    (1,'parent1'),
    (2,'parent2'),
    (3,'parent3')
), child (id, parent, name, age) as ( values
    (1,1,'child1',2),
    (2,1,'child2',4),
    (3,1,'child3',7),
    (4,2,'child12',5)
)
select
    p.name,
    array_agg(array[to_jsonb(c.name), to_jsonb(c.age)]::jsonb[]) as children
from
    parent p
    inner join
    child c on p.id = c.parent
group by p.name
;
  name   |                       children                       
---------+------------------------------------------------------
 parent1 | {{"\"child1\"",2},{"\"child2\"",4},{"\"child3\"",7}}
 parent2 | {{"\"child12\"",5}}
```